# Smooth zoom and pan in OpenLayers?

Tags: zooming, openlayers, smoothing, pan

I was wondering, has smooth zooming and panning described in http://www.win.tue.nl/~vanwijk/zoompan.pdf been implemented in OpenLayers?

It has been implemented for PolyMaps: http://bl.ocks.org/RandomEtc/600144
And ModestMaps: https://github.com/stamen/modestmaps-js/tree/master/examples/zoompan

Comment: Are you thinking about this: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/transition.html ?

Comment: There is also smooth panning: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/animated_panning.html

Comment: Both examples are different from what I'm searching for. If you check the code on https://github.com/stamen/modestmaps-js/tree/master/examples/zoompan it is quite elaborate. If it's not done yet and if I find time I will try to convert it to OL myself ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since 3.20.0, OpenLayers has an [`ol.View.animate()`](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.View.html#animate) method that allows smooth zooming and/or panning (among others) and deprecates the old [`ol.animation`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.0/apidoc/ol.animation.html).

From the [latest API docs](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.View.html#animate):

> The view's **center**, **zoom** (or **resolution**), and **rotation** can be animated for smooth transitions between view states.

So, you can *zoom and pan* by doing:

```
var view = map.getView();
view.animate({
    center: coordinates,
    zoom:   zoomLevel
});
```